# AWS Lambda support HTTP/2 - Server Push and Ping?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, http2

I am using AWS CloudFront. 
And I'm going to use lambda as the cloudfront origin.

I need to use http/2 - server push and ping.
Does aws-lambda support these? server-push and ping?

Comment: cloudfront doesn't support it